# How can I get an average formula that omits errors

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the average of four data points.
The problem is that one or more data points could be missing.

The average should be the average of the last four mondays or four last tuesdays etc.
Each data point is about 1000 rows apart so my idea was to "list" the dates needed and use vlookup and average.

Generic formula

```
// I only add two dates, but the same formula is repeated for four dates
=AVERAGE(VLOOKUP(DATE_1;Table;25;FALSE);VLOOKUP(DATE_2;Table;25;FALSE))
```

The DATE_1 and DATE_2 is dynamic calculations of the previous two, lets say mondays.
This works if all dates are there, but if one monday is missing VLOOKUP returns an error and the error can't be calculated as an average.
I figured I could wrap VLOOKUP with IFERROR, but I can't get that working either

```
// for simplicity I removed the average and only show one. 
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DATE_1;Table;25;FALSE);"") // returns empty string, can't calculate

IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DATE_1;Table;25;FALSE);0) // Works, but it skews the result with a zero.
```

I know AVERAGE skips empty cells, but how can I "emulate" a empty cell. `""` is empty string and that is not the same.
Is there formula that can handle errors and still give me the average, or a formula that returns "empty cell"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the whole point of [the `AGGREGATE` function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df).

Instead of `AVERAGE(SomeRange)`, use `AGGREGATE(1, 6, SomeRange)`.  Instead of `AVERAGE(Value1, Value2)`, use `AGGREGATE(1, 6, Value1, Value2)`

The `1` tells `AGGREGATE` to calculate the `AVERAGE`, and the `6` tells it "Ignore error values".  A full list of the values is at the bottom of this post

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,VLOOKUP(DATE_1;Table;25;FALSE);VLOOKUP(DATE_2;Table;25;FALSE))
```

(As people have pointed out, this doesn't quite work properly without interim calculation cells - when you use a Formula in the function, Excel refuses to accept it in Reference Form)

Reference form: `AGGREGATE(function_num, options, ref1, [ref2], …)`
Array form: `AGGREGATE(function_num, options, array, [k])`

```
Function_num | Function 
      1      | AVERAGE
      2      | COUNT
      3      | COUNTA
      4      | MAX
      5      | MIN
      6      | PRODUCT
      7      | STDEV.S
      8      | STDEV.P
      9      | SUM
     10      | VAR.S
     11      | VAR.P
     12      | MEDIAN
     13      | MODE.SNGL
     14      | LARGE
     15      | SMALL
     16      | PERCENTILE.INC
     17      | QUARTILE.INC
     18      | PERCENTILE.EXC
     19      | QUARTILE.EXC
```

```
Option | Behaviour
   0   | Ignore nested SUBTOTAL and AGGREGATE functions
   1   | Ignore hidden rows, nested SUBTOTAL and AGGREGATE functions 
   2   | Ignore error values, nested SUBTOTAL and AGGREGATE functions
   3   | Ignore hidden rows, error values, nested SUBTOTAL and AGGREGATE functions
   4   | Ignore nothing
   5   | Ignore hidden rows
   6   | Ignore error values
   7   | Ignore hidden rows and error values
```

Comment: Works great! Didn't think about Aggregate

Comment: @Andreas & Chronocidal out of curiosity and for my own learning benefit, how did you make it work? I thought that `AGGREGATE` only works with array of values and won't work with functions. As per documentation: `The function will not ignore hidden rows, nested subtotals or nested aggregates if the array argument includes a calculation` See the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/V6TXJpK.png) where I couldn't make it work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: + further to that point, it looks like `=AGGREGATE(1,6,B1,B2)` works if `B1=1` and `B2=#N/A` (i.e. `B2` has a value of `#N/A`), but it doesn't work if the second `#N/A` is a result of a function instead of a value itself. Some exemplary functions that won't work even though they should ignore an error value: `=AGGREGATE(1,6,B1,B2/0)` (#DIV/0! error - not ignored), `=AGGREGATE(1,6,B1,MATCH(2,B1:B2,0))` (#REF! or #VALUE! errors - not ignored). I'm curious about your input.

Comment: @JustynaMK You are correct that it didn't work per se. But I cheated... I added four helper columns one with each of the four dates, that meant I had a cell referens to point to and that worked. I just added the folmulas at a point of the sheet that is empty and changed the font color to white and I could use the aggregate function. See screenshot of my actual worksheet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JO8T.png

Comment: Ah makes sense, that will work. In that case `AGGREGATE` function is taking error values as arguments, not errors resulting from the `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` function. Thanks for clarifying @Andreas

Comment: Justyna MK is correct that the answer does not work as it's written. But it will work if you create helper columns. You should include that in the answer @Chronocidal

Answer (score 2):

Just giving you a different approach even though it is not exactly the same way as your question is going, I just thought to share how i've solved a similar issue.

No lookup table in this one, I personnally try to avoid these in these situations, as you always have to update them given some conditions.

```
{=AVERAGE(IF((WEEKDAY(A1:A276,2)=1)*((L1:L276)>0)*((A1:A276)>((TODAY())-29)),L1:L276,""))}
```

array formula, so ctrl+shift+enter

`(WEEKDAY(A1:A276,2)=1)`   tests if it's a monday

`(L1:L276)>0)`             is where I have values and therefore want to ignore zeros

`((A1:A276)>((TODAY())-29))` added this one for you to check if it's less than 4 weeks old

if these conditions are fulfilled the respective value in L:L is take for the average (A:A being the date in this example)

Comment: This will not work in my case. Usually it will work fine, but the dates are not dates. The dates in A column is text. I can't make it dates because that makes all my pivot tables dates incorrect and I can't change them. I have a question a few weeks ago about it. Something is wrong and it's impossible to change.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more solution for you to try (array formula - Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$10,CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},DATE_1,DATE_2,DATE_3,DATE_4),0)),$B$1:$B$10))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is DATE_1 a named range of F1 in your example?

Comment: Hi @Andreas, correct, all four ranges are linked to cells F1:F4. Glad it's all working for you!

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX & MATCH` doesn't produce the same problem, try this:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(YourColumnRange;MATCH(DATE_1;Table));INDEX(YourColumnRange;MATCH(DATE_2;Table)))
```

EDIT: To match your dataset you can manually calculate an average like this:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH(Date_1,A:A,0)),0), IFERROR(INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH(Date_2,A:A,0)),0))/
COUNT(INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH(Date_1,A:A,0)), INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH(Date_2,A:A,0)))
```

This will allow you to skip empty rows. The formula is simplified for a generic case to make it easier to read.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it seems it returns the previous days value, in my case if monday is missing it returns sunday. If I make the MATCH exact with ´0` then it returns missing which is the same as VLOOKUP.

Comment: @Andreas Can you post the exact formula you're using, that still produces the error?

Comment: `=INDEX(Statistik!Y:Y;PASSA(TEXT($H$2-VECKODAG($H$2-1;A23);"ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD");Statistik!A:A;0))` in English that is `=INDEX(Statistik!Y:Y,MATCH(TEXT($H$2-WEEKDAY($H$2-1,A23),"YYYY-MM-DD"),Statistik!A:A,0))` I need the TEXT and WEEKDAY thing to return the date as a string and not as a date (number). In this case the TEXT and what is inside returns : "2019-09-21" which is last saturday.

Comment: Here is an example I made that is easy to overview https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZoyo.png or better example https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRFSp.png . The formula is the same in each column, only the cell reference changes

Comment: I would suspect the error is somewhere inside this part: `TEXT($H$2-WEEKDAY($H$2-1,A23),"YYYY-MM-DD")`. That `-WEEKDAY(...)` part seems weird to me. In the sreenshot everything seems to work fine, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry look at the edit. As you can see the return is 0 if I turn off exact match

Comment: Ahh I see the problem now. The sample data I tried it on has data in the first column, but no corresponding value in the second column (so "2019-09-22" in cell F3 but an empty cell in G3). But in your example the entire row is empty. I don't know of a way to do it in that case. Would filling the entire first column, but leaving the corresponding value empty, work for you?

Comment: I can't do that, the data comes in automatically. The reason it's sometimes missing is because the web service is down or my computer has restarted by some reason

Comment: I added an edit to the answer that should solve your problem